# creating elements inside of DOM with JS

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I'm a beginner so I'm sorry for a stupid question. The matter is I can't add div "title" inside of div "app" using JS. Help me please.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset = "utf-8">
        <meta name = "description" content = "Field v.1">
        <title> Field v.1 </title>

        <style>
        .app{
            background-color: 'black';
        }
        .title{
            background-color: 'green';
        }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class = "app">
        </div>

        <script>
            var app = document.querySelector('.app')
            var title = document.createElement('div')
            title.className = 'title'
            title.innerHTML = "BREAKING NEWS"
            app.appendChild(title);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: your desired behaviour is there. Unless some syntactical optimisations you're code is fine.

Comment: Press the "Show code snippet" link and then "Run code snippet" button. It works! As @andrei-gheorghiu mentioned, you just have to fix your CSS.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got my mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JavaScript works perfectly. Here's the result of your JS:

```
<div class="app">
  <div class="title">BREAKING NEWS</div>
</div>
```

However, there's a small problem with your CSS. **Do not quote CSS values!**. It should be:

```
.app{
    background-color: black;
}
.title{
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset = "utf-8">
  <meta name = "description" content = "Field v.1">
  <title> Field v.1 </title>

  <style>
  .app{
   background-color: black;
  }
  .title{
   background-color: green;
  }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div class = "app">
  </div>

  <script>
   var app = document.querySelector('.app')
   var title = document.createElement('div')
   title.className = 'title'
   title.innerHTML = "BREAKING NEWS"
   app.appendChild(title);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And here's the demo of it running on CodePen: https://codepen.io/sbolel/pen/QmOKEY/ -- edit: ah, the run snippet button in @andrei-gheorghiu's answer shows it working as well! 

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your JS code.
You can see your working code in this Codepen:

https://codepen.io/kmpkt/pen/bvYwpm

But there is a error in your CSS code. CSS values may not be quoted:

```
background-color: black;
```